# Should I use a public repo for a commercial application?

Tags: amazon-mws

Surprisingly, I can't find any information or opinions on this from Googling. I'm developing a commercial application and I'm considering using a public Amazon MWS repo. It doesn't have a lot of activity, so I'm worried about using it.

The things I'm worried about are, potential backdoors; bugs that need to be fixed; the repo going cold; and the unknown. At this point, I'm just going to do it myself, but I thought I would ask the community to get some other thoughts?

Comment: You could always use a local repo with say Git, and back it up to private S3 storage on Amazon.  If you use archives / snapshots you're also protected from it getting corrupted somehow.

Comment: That's a good thought, but corruption isn't so much of a worry to me as malintent. I wouldn't worry so much if the repo had a significant number of pulls, but when it's a lesser known one... It makes me cautious and I don't know if that's paranoia or if I have a legitimate reason to feel that way.